# Server 2012R2 Thick Provisioned Disk VSphere

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, vmware-esx, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Server 2012R2 VM running on a VSphere ESXi 5.0.0 (1489271) Host. It has been updated and patched to allow support for 2012R2.

Within my VM I have several disks (Thick Provisioned). However, upon deleting data on these disks, Explorer does not see the free space - in fact, after deleting about 120GB of data, one disk still has only 2GB free.

I'm stumped. Disk Management also reflects the same data as Windows Explorer with respect to the free space - is this a VMWare thing, or a Windows thing? Any ideas?

Even WinDirStat is showing incorrect stats. See images in WinDirStat and Explorer.

[image: WinDirStat Stats of one of the problem drive]

[image: Drive in Explorer]

[image: Properties of all folders in the Drive]

Comment: Can you post a WinDirStat of the drive in question?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/windirstat/

Comment: Definitely not a VMware thing. Have you checked whether you have any stuck VSS (not VMware) snapshots on the drive? That might be causing the data to stay around even after you've deleted it.

Comment: No VSS snapshots. Will try and get WinDirStat.

Comment: Updated with images.

Comment: Do you have deduplication enabled?

Comment: Yes - could this be the cause?

Comment: Very much so - unless you're deleting unique blocks then you won't free up any space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2897997

You need to schedule and run a garbage collection job to free up no-longer-needed blocks. If you haven't done that, do it. If you still have issues, see the support article linked above.

See this article for info on how to properly set up dedupe jobs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831434.aspx#BKMK_JOBS

It's not just next, next, next, done from the GUI.

Comment: MDMarra, thanks, I already tried the Garbage Collection which wasn't clawing back the space. However the above hotfix did resolve the problem. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this problem was to simply robocopy the data off to another disk (NAS etc.) and reformat the drive in question - then finally copy the data back. Quite a frustration given I am dealing with 100GBs of data but such as life.

Potentially a command line that would of resolved the freespace issue

```
Start-DedupJob E: –Type GarbageCollection -full
```